# How to execute stored procedure in loop

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo, phalcon

I am facing an issue. Please have a look at the below code:

```
// $data having 1000 entries
foreach($data as $key=>$value) {     
    $resultStore = $this->db->query("call get_parents(" . $value['id'] . ")");

    $dataStore = $resultStore->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
}
```

The problem is that the loop only executes a single time. 
Note that I am using the Phalcon framework.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data only as arguments on `execute` . In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for advice on how to avoid problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your index is `id` but this does not make sense and therefore you call the stored procedure with the same - undefined - value. Fix the parameter of the stored procedure.

Comment: How can you be sure there is no value in `$value['id']` ?

Comment: HI AI Bundy,
I am getting values for $value['id'].